# AVPlayer working but not visible in a subview

Tags: ios, uikit, avplayer

I'm trying to add a subview once button is clicked, then bring it to front and add an AVPlayer instance to play radio streaming. Audio is playing, but AVPlayer is not visible, I'm not sure how to make AVPlayer visible an place it in the subview. I've been searching for an example and information in Apple Library, but it's poor about it.

Here is the call method:

```
- (IBAction)radioButton:(id)sender {

    radioButton.selected=TRUE;
    twitterButton.selected=FALSE;

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:radioView];
    radioView.hidden = FALSE;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://streaming3.radiocat.net:80/"];
                  // You may find a test stream at <http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8>.
    self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    //[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [self.player play];
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: So what is the code in the accepted answer to get the AVPlayer to appear? We are having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVPlayer does not have its own UI, you have to create it yourself from UIKit classes and connect the relevant IBAction messages from their operation to methods that control the AVPlayer instance.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. You mean add UIButton action to play method, and volume control to UISlider, for instance?

Comment: Precisely: for playback have the UIButton's action method trigger AVPlayer's play and pause methods; volume works differently though, depending on how you are using AVPlayer – take a look at [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get started.